# Looking for title of SciFi book, main character has 3 spots on his arm

Tags: story-identification

Set on a future Earth taken over by an alien race. Humans reduced to prisoners/cattle? (memories of a bunch being kept in a fenced area ala pow's) The aliens have stripped most of the planets resources and are now turning to any buried refuse sites etc to remove all metals for their use.

I recall part of the plot where the aliens have a small base and are tunneling into a hill trying to reach what turns out to be an old army weapons cache.
Our guy (human/ish) manages to get into the base through the hill? (not realising the value/use of the weapons crated up in the cave thing) where he finds a clinic of sorts where the aliens are force breeding the humans and modifying the offspring? He discovers he has 3 dots on his arm like the modified babies and must be one himself.

I think there are chases, fights etc that lead through radioactive hot zones so he can escape. Though I may be mixing this in from another plot?

Any assistance would be great, this has been nagging me off and on for years.

I have read a lot of the other queries on the forum also, but they are not what I am looking for, nor have I been able to help anyone else..... yet!

Comment: Is this a novel, a short story, a movie, a comic book, something else?

Comment: It is a novel, paperback when read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[Creatures of the Claw](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7227390-creatures-of-the-claw)" by Douglas Hill.

> Finn Ferral, the main character in the novel, is a young hunter in an
>   isolated village at the beginning of the trilogy, but by the time this
>   novel opens, he has crossed most of a continent and has met with many
>   strange events and people. In the course of rescuing his foster father
>   and sister, who were taken by Slavers, he has further honed his
>   already-sharp tracking and survival skills, and he has learned much
>   about the Slavers' operations and machinery.
>
> But many things about them still remain a mystery to be uncovered as
>   events in this novel unfold.
>
> Finn is also a young man of somewhat mysterious origins. His foster
>   father, Joshua, found him as a toddler wandering in the forest. In the
>   previous novel, during a stay at the Slaver base, he found that the
>   raised dots on his arm marked him as a product of the [clone vats?].

[image]

The blurb from the earlier book in the series mentions that the Earth's resources have been depleted...

> [Alien Citadel](http://www.bookrags.com/shortguide-alien-citadel/setting.html) takes place on Earth, but on a future Earth that only
>   barely resembles our own world. In this future world, humans live in
>   fear, hiding from the Slavers, the planet's new masters. The planet is
>   covered by desert wasteland, forested wilderness, and radioactive
>   firesands where monstrous mutant creatures prowl. There is no more
>   civilization and little hope. The Citadel, built underground in a
>   mountain hideaway, is where the Slavers take those humans whom they
>   spare for use as slave labor: child-bearingage women are used for
>   breeding experiments, and the rest of the captives are used as
>   laborers in the Slavers' mines.
>
> As the novel opens, Finn Ferral has just travelled across a continent
>   strewn with dangers. Slavers run rampant over the planet, scouring the
>   land with heat weapons in their efforts to eliminate any humans and
>   other "vermin" still infesting its farthest reaches.

Comment: This sounds very much like the one I'm after! Thank You! I will get copies of these asap!