# Old sci-fi novel: post alien invasion, girl called Steelfinder, aliens choked in too-dry air

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, alien-invasion

The story is set on earth, post alien invasion war, humans mostly enslaved.

The story centers around a group of humans struggling to avoid capture, having to be careful where they go because there's pockets of radiation around. One of the humans is a girl, who I think was called Steelfinder.

The lead male character gets caught and called a rat by the aliens because they dont have a word for human. One of his friends rescues him by shutting off the air conditioning and the aliens who captured him choke to death in the too-dry air.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59800/looking-for-title-of-scifi-book-main-character-has-3-spots-on-his-arm (same series)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Alien Citadel](https://books.google.com/books?id=rnZ4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=Steelfinder&source=bl&ots=zUl5p_uBAS&sig=xgUn62TAEj1afmqah9rsse7vFPM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij5aDqvpnLAhUHKWMKHRY0DcoQ6AEIYzAN#v=onepage&q=Steelfinder&f=false) by Douglas Hill.

It has a girl named Steelfinder.

> Steelfinder's eyes lit up. Lithely, she sprang to the tunnel.

An alien named Cacinnix calls one of the main male characters, Finn, a rat.

> "Clever little rat," Cacinnix said through the machine.
>   ...
>   "...How long has my rat been wandering room to room?"

Comment: In the future, please try to include portions of the story or a summary that address the points the OP remembers, to help verify the story. (Sometimes they don't come back and accept an answer, but a good inclusion of matching points lets the community know it *is* correct. That way we can give you the upvotes you deserve!) I've added them in for you this time (you may want to do the same for some of your answers). In the future, I'll might just steal your answer for myself while I'm doing the work ;)